# GetUserName Win32 API returns wrong value for MS Live account on windows 8

Tags: winapi, windows-8

I'm using GetUserName() Win32 API to get the username, but I found that  GetUserName() Win32 API returns wrong value for **MS Live** account,if I Setup MS live user account on my windows 8 machine under user settings.

For example **xyz@live.com** is my live account for this account GetUserName() API returns value as **xyz_000**.

note:It returns correct value for all other user except **MS Live** account user.

Comment: If you go under C:\Users how does the username appear there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That function returns the user name of the account on that particular Windows machine.  That may or may not match the user name of any particular online service that the user had signed in to.